# Brings sets together into one data. (in macro) in SAS

Tags: sas, set, sas-macro

i want to brings sets together into one data in macro. I have 1064 sets from zm_&next_name and i want to brings them into one data for example ----> data CramerSet;
I want to do it in macro

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without a macro. Just use the `:` operator when defining your data sets.

This feature is nice when you have a constant string that represents the beginning strings of the data set. Even if the strings change, as long as your target strings are constant (like your `zm_` data sets) this is a good solution.

```
data CramerSet;
set zm_:;
run;
```

Once you run this, check your log. You will see a readout of every `zm_%` data set that has been concatenated.

If you are in fact hellbent on doing this with a macro - just use the data step above and use the string constant as your macro argument. Then if your string constant changes (maybe you have 1,025 data sets that start with `ym_...`, just use the new string constant as your macro string.